# How can I group by a 10 second group in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have data that is collected every 10 seconds.  I want to group by a 10 second group to compare against each group. So I'll have 6 groups (00, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50).  Then I can use a box plot for each series/group.

I tried using a grouper but without success.

```
groups = df.reset_index().groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='10s', axis=1))
```

Here is a small sample of the data.

```
                      value
date                       
2012-01-01 01:00:00    5.0
2012-01-01 01:00:10   16.5
2012-01-01 01:00:20   28.5
2012-01-01 01:00:30   40.5
2012-01-01 01:00:40   43.2     
2012-01-01 01:00:50   33.2 
2012-01-01 01:01:00   15.0
2012-01-01 01:01:10   14.5
2012-01-01 01:01:20   38.5
2012-01-01 01:01:30   30.5
2012-01-01 01:01:40   33.2     
2012-01-01 01:01:50   23.2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you don't need to group the data, just a new column for seconds and the boxplot that column to value:

First make sure your index is datetimeindex

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

df['10_second'] = df.index.second
df.boxplot('value','10_second')
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you have a `datetime` index, you can group by the *second* of the index:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df.groupby(df.index.second).sum()

#  value
#0  20.0
#10 31.0
#20 67.0
#30 71.0
#40 76.4
#50 56.4
```

Comment: @MBeale needs it grouped into 10-second buckets, not 1-second buckets.

Comment: @RagingRoosevelt Sure. But OP's data is collected every 10 second.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new column that takes the value in the date column (we'll call this x) and gives `x.timestamp() % 10)`.  This will give you values of 10 seconds.

```
df['timestamp'] = df.apply(lambda row: x.timestamp() % 10, axis=1)
```

Next, use can use group-by over the values in this new column to group your data.

---

Or, if you need to break up by increments of 10 seconds rather than into 6 groups of 10s each, you could do:

```
df['timestamp'] = df.apply(lambda row: 10*(x.timestamp() // 10), axis=1)
```